# Is $x^2$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I am really stuck on this question!! I would love some help.

Comment: There can't be a $\delta$ such that for all $y>x$, 

$y - x < \delta \Longrightarrow y^2 - x^2 < \epsilon$ since

$$y^2 - x^2 = (y+x)(y-x) < \delta(y+x)$$

and we can make this greater than $\epsilon$ by choosing $x,y$ large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ by finding two sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ such that
$x_n\to+\infty$, $y_n\to+\infty$, $x_n-y_n\to 0$, but $f(x_n)-f(y_n)\not\to 0$.

Hint. Take $y_n=n$ and $x_n=n+\frac{1}{n^a}$ with the exponent $a>0$ to be chosen.

P.S. This criteria follows by negating the definition of uniform continuity. See this [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Cauchy_continuity).